# Who is going to edit the question next?

Tags: discussion, editing

Looking at the [revisions of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/149937/revisions) made me think some unnecessary edits were done. Clearly, the third edit is completely unnecessary. Also, too much edits has changed the problem. Please be more careful while trying to figure out if an edit should be approved or rejected or improved.

Comment: Which one do you refer as the third edit? From my counting, the third edit is mine and I believe that the edit was definitely necessary. First, `$$ $$` should never be used in titles along with `\displaystyle` and secondly the question should be asked in the body of the post and not in the title.

Answer (score 8):

This has nothing at all to do with approval of edits.

It is very clearly a case of cross-editing which is frustrating for the first editor whose edit is overwritten, but is the inevitable result of a post so badly written that many people start to edit it simultaneously.

In case you saw the question after the third edit, I would have suggested that you roll back to your edit and leave a comment that you assume a cross-edit.

I find it more annoying that the post is still asking for an explantion after five edits.

With regard to the introduced error: This error was introduced in version 3 which was clearly a cross-edit of the first version. So, yes, an error has been made, but it had nothing to do with the high number of edits.

Comment: It's very clearly not a case of cross-editing since I saw the second edit about one or two minutes after mine.

Comment: And What I am saying is the number of edits which have changed nothing important about the question is to much and this fact has changed the problem itself to something which wasn't intended to ask!

Comment: @Gigili Cross-editing does not mean that you have the same time-stamp, it means that the second editor edited the first version and never saw your version. And I can just repeat that the error was introduced in version 3 which was experienced by the editor as a first edit, so it has nothing to do with the number of edits.